# Draw text over a Gridview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating a Walkthrough for my app, when the user clicks on the grid item, a text should be drawn over it, describing the item, how do I go about that. Are there any better ways of showing a walkthrough?

Answer (score 0):

As you have to show different explanation for each item you clicked, instead of drawing text on gridView item, I think its better to show in a `dialog`. When you complete reading, you can remove that dialog and show for next item and so on.

Comment: I would like to know whether i can draw over a gridview

Comment: If I am not wrong, you can draw, in the sense, placing a textView over a transparent layer above your grid item and setting text to that textView when you click